# Formula using Sum product calculate total hours in overlapping date array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help,

I want to calculate the actual downtime per each type of equipment and per each type of work order, as shown in the following table sample of the data which extend in real file to 6000 rows:

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oskyo.jpg)

, when I use this formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(K2:K6000,"<"&MIN(K2:K6000)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((MAX(L2:L6000)-MIN(K2:K6000))*1440,0)))/1440-1/2880,L2:L6000,">"&MIN(K2:K6000)+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((MAX(L2:L6000)-MIN(K2:K6000))*1440,0)))/1440-1/2880,G2:G6000,"*"&P3&"*",A2:A6000,"PRMN")>0)+0)/60}
```

I take a long time to calculate as I use it for 6000 rows with extra 2 criteria, so how I can improve this formula to be faster?

Best Regards,
Mahmoud Hazem

Comment: Are you entering this as an array formula?

Comment: It is better to provide some sample data and the goal you want to achieve in order to help with a faster approach. Just looking at the formula, one suggestion is to have separate columns for MIN() and MAX() so that you don't need to calculate it several times per row, but the saving would not be very significant.

Comment: thanks, @OliverLeung, I tried this solution but after a deep search I think the issue is with the following function:

{ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((MAX(L2:L6000)-MIN(K2:K6000))*1440,0)))}

so how I can minimize the range produced by it or make it faster?

Comment: @mahmoudhazemElayady, without more information, it is difficult to help. 
Anyway, based on your description, I made some guesses. If you really want to use Array Formula, the "Total actual UP time of order type "PRMN" and equipment type "*"&P3&"*" is equal to sum(Col L - Col K) for entries with desired Order/Equipment type, i.e. `=SUM((A2:A6000="PRMN")*(G2:G6000="*"&P3&"*")*(L2:L6000-K2:K6000))`.  Remember to use "Ctrl-Shift-Enter" to input the formula.   Down time could then be done by a subtraction by the supposed operation time.